# Event.observe inefficient with prototype Javascript, alternatives?

Tags: javascript, jsf, prototypejs, dom-events

We have a table with a lot of checkboxes, onchange of a checkbox we want to call some Javascript.
We use something similar to this snippet:

```
addEventObserver(elementId){
        // ($= means 'ends with') this is required for elementIds which are in a table and get prepended with some id
        $$('[id$=:'+elementId+']').each(function(e) {
            Event.observe(e, 'change', function(event) {
                submitAction(something);
            });
        });
}
```

So below an input checkbox we add a Javascript function call:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="somename" id="somePrependedIdsomeId">    
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                    addEventObserver('someId');
                </script>
```

this works fine with our test environment settings. In production though we have tables with ~700 checkboxes and this makes the browser/cpu get stuck.

We use jsf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would scrap adding an event listener to every single checkbox in favour of writing a single "smart" event handler attached to a container element. Here is a simple example:

```
var theDiv = document.getElementById("foo");
theDiv.onchange = function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input" 
          && e.target.type.toLowerCase() == "checkbox") {
        alert("do something");
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xFC3A/

The onchange event is thus captured by the container div which is bubbles up to. The event attached to the div can test for the type of element that triggered the event (the [source/target element depending on the browser](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target)) and react accordingly. Main advantages are:

1. Only one event handler - no time wasted binding handlers to hundreds of elements.
2. It will continue to work on  dynamically added elements (via AJAX, JS etc.).

[Read more about Event Delegation.](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/)

Some useful reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

Comment: Also an excellent point. One event handler vs. 700 event handlers will definitely boost performance.

Comment: just a question... the theDiv.onchange behaves the same like the Event.observe? I just ran into odd behaviour with compatibility when it comes to events... e.g. <input type="checkbox" name="cb" onchange="iewill not call changeevent unless clicking occurs outside the checkbox"/>

Comment: @Toskan - Are you using Prototype of plain-JS? Which browser?

Comment: It didn't work in IE 8... i found the problem. IE 8 is very very bad when it comes to event handling. Onchange is not triggered (for whatever stupidity). Onclick on the other hand results in something working - still it is disappointing  - onclick is triggered for every click, even one on the background.

Comment: @Toskan - maybe try putting the above into `window.onload = function() { //above code here }`

Comment: that doesn't help. Don't worry i'll accept your answer as soon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much of a Prototype jockey (much more of a jQuery guy), but generally speaking, any selector using an attribute selector is going to be slow. If you're running that selector on 700+ items, you're going to hit a massive slowdown for sure.

You're also using Prototype's `each()` method... could you re-write things to use a native javascript for() loop instead? Again, referring to jQuery here, but I've gotten INCREDIBLE performance gains by using native JS rather than library methods whenever possible. I've sped a web app by 20x by removing a bunch of jQuery .each() methods and replacing them with native for() loops.

Answer (score 1):

I think Event Delegation should help you, simple attach die EventHandler to the Parent of all Checkboxes

```
$('container').observe("change", changeBy);

function changeBy(e){
                if (e.element().identify() != "container") {
            doChange(e.element());
        }
}

function doChange(elem){
  submitAction(something);
}
```

Markup:

```
<div id="container"> <input type="checkbox" > ... </div>
```

You doesn't need to do the foreach and you doesn't have hundreds of eventhandler, you simple have one EventHandler, this is pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

Prototype already provides event delegation by way of [`Event.on`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/):

```
$('id_of_table').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', some_handler_function);
```

Comment: I've heard IE is poor at bubbling events (which delegation relies on) so it's possible this doesn't work. I've not tested it explicitly.